# given a url address of a html file, how to read the content?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to do something simple,

I have `canvas.html`

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Something.</p>
</div>
```

Now I want to read the content of `canvas.html`

```
function LoadPage(href)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
}

...
var canvasPanelURL = "myfolder/canvas.html";
var content = LoadPage(canvasPanelURL);
..
```

The code above is correct.

Sadly, `XMLHttpRequest` is deprecated, I want to use `FileReader` but the input is blob, any other way to do this instead using `XMLHttpRequest`?

EDIT

Thanks for the comment, Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` is deprecated, 
I just want to know if there's any other alternatives reading a html file given a url (I should say, the question is loosely related to `XMLHttpRequest`)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is **not** deprecated. Synchronous requests are. Change  `false` to `true` (or remove the argument entirely) and use a callback instead of a return value.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest ` + `synchronous` = You're doing something really wrong here.

Comment: the main point is to read a file given an url, not XMLHttpRequest, I know it's wrong but this is why I hate stackoverflow if I have a really nasty code I get downvoted...

Comment: @azer89 You make incorrect claims, I guess that's what gets you downvoted. Do you understand what the comments mean? Do you need help with async XHR?

Comment: @Xan, I know and I tried Asynchronous XMLHttpRequest, with a little success, I also explicitly state that I would like to know the solution if using FileReader but nobody cares...

Comment: Well then. You should include code that you tried to use, either with async XHR or FileReader, so we can see what your problem is.

Comment: why don't you use jQuery and $.ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly synchronous requests on the main thread (i.e. the one running your javascript) has been deprecated.

> Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

You can however still run synchronous web requests by using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Example.3A_Synchronous_HTTP_request_from_a_Worker).

The alternative to using a web worker is to do your processing in the callback of an asynchronous request

```
function LoadPage(href, cb)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", href, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            cb(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var canvasPanelURL = "myfolder/canvas.html";
LoadPage(canvasPanelURL, function(content) {
    // do stuff with content
});
```

You can then manually create a `FileReader` as you can create a `Blob` from an array of entries (1 in your case). I can't say I can see why you would want to do this if you have already loaded your html file using AJAX though.

```
var blob = new Blob([content]);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```